# How to ignore the provided primary key in an SQL insert?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with 10 rows of data, having the primary keys: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`.

I want to run in an `INSERT` statement containing 5 new rows, these rows having the primary keys: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

My question: is there a way to have the primary keys of the five new rows set to the table's auto-increment value when I `INSERT` these 5 rows into the table? I want to ignore their initial primary key values of `1,2,3,4,5` (otherwise they'd be duplicates)

**Update:** The reason *just removing* the primary key ID from the insert set would be difficult is that our actual data set is 15MB in size, not just five rows. I'm using MySQLWorkbench (mac) so if there is a way to export the rows WITHOUT the primary key ID please tell.

Comment: Why are you trying to insert duplicate keys in the first place?  If the PK is an `IDENTITY` then just don't supply a PK value when performing the insert.

Comment: Just remove them from the insert statement. Fixed.

Comment: What kind of sql are you using?
For example - in ms sql server, you can set the id column as identity column. Then Id will be incremented automatically, you will not have to specify it in the insert.

Comment: The insert data is large and I'm not sure how it's possible to remove the primary key ids in a way that wouldn't take days.

Comment: mb my question is similar to yours [insert-value-without-setting-primary-key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117505/insert-value-without-setting-primary-key)

Answer (score 3):

consider the format of an insert statement

```
insert into TBL [(col1,col2,...)] values (val1,val2,...)
```

so if your table has three columns id,a,b

```
insert into TBL (a,b) values (avalue,bvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

If primary key is identity column in your table then while inserting those five records, don't mention that column in insert statement so that your table can auto generate the primary key field value and store in table.