# insert value without setting primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i got minimal database like so

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reg_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;
```

then i try to insert new user, setting only username/email/pass

> "INSERT INTO `users` SET name='user_name', email='users_email', `pass = 'users_top_secret_pass."';

or every time i ned insert new id like:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `pass`, `reg_time`) VALUES
(1, 'user', 'user@server.com', 'pass', '2016-01-31 03:10:13');
```

name and email are UNIQUE, time is default current timestamp and i no need  to test them. This is good but how i can be insert id, and does i need it?

testing on local phpmyadmin gives me nothing new.

upd: removed outdated code with php functions, only sql.

Comment: You don't need to insert a value for `id`.  That is what `auto_increment` does.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: thx but on 99% where i work it php5. and about auto_increment, without setting it i got errors. mb problem on mysql side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omg, just setting null, and it good works!!!!

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `pass`, `reg_time`) VALUES
(null, 'user', 'user@server.com', 'pass', null);
```

Comment: This is answer is for specific version of mysql.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ( `name`, `email`, `pass` ) values('".$user."', '".$email."', '".$pass."') ");
```

Insert query syntax wrong you are using update query syntax in you code..

Comment: MySQL supports `set` for `insert`.  This is a MySQL extension.  You can read about it in the documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query is having id, if your table is not having any record with id 1 which is your table's primary key then it will work correct. If table is having and record with id 1 then it will cause a Fatal error.
Note:- basically primary key of table should be auto incremented. For date time auto update in PHPMyadmin set column default value for CURRENT_DATETIME.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `pass`, `reg_time`) VALUES
('user', 'user@server.com', 'pass', '2016-01-31 03:10:13');
```